# Half star not positioned correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, razor-pages

I implemented a star rating system in my website, however, I have one problem: the half stars aren't positioned correctly on mobile (iPhone 11). They look like this:
[image]

CSS code:

```
.star {
    font-size: x-large;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: gray;
}

.star:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.star:before {
    content: '\2605';
}

.star.on {
    color: orange;
}

.star.half:after {
    content: '\2605';
    color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="stars">
        @for (int i = 0; i < StarRatingInt; i++)
        {
            <span class="star on"></span>
        }
        @if (Model.StarRating > StarRatingInt)
        {
            <span class="star half"></span>
        }
        @for (int i = 0; i < 5 - Math.Round(Model.StarRating, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); i++)
        {
            <span class="star"></span>
        }
    </div>
```

I have spent a few hours troubleshooting this issue to no avail. I've searched for other star rating systems but none of them look the way I want them to.

Comment: white-space:nowrap on stars?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this definitely helped... The half star now looks like this: https://imgur.com/gallery/CCqCvXU. Although it still isn't exactly positioned. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Through `.star.half:after`, you have put half star on `absolute` position. So it is needed to add the `position:relative` css attribute to parent class `.star` to put the half star inside the star item.

```
.star {
  font-size: x-large;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;

  /* This part is required */
  position: relative;
}
```